# jQuery Draggable + Droppable + nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am completely new to jQuery, but have managed to put together a nice little app that drags, drops, and rotates items.

Looking for any guidance suggestions on finding a function that would let me do the following (apologize for any terminology issues):

- Create a div that is the droppable, such as a small box (done)
- Create a div that is the draggable, such as an icon (done)
- Drag the icon into the larger div
- Then be able to drag the larger div while also carrying the icons, and doing an AJAX post to my PHP script on everything that is moved.

I found this: http://boagworld.com/dev/creating-a-draggable-sitemap-with-jquery/ however, it snaps everything to the structure, and doesn`t really allow free movement. I also couldn't figure out which function in there causes the parent to move the child.

Thanks for any guidance, articles, or links to examples! A couple days of searching in my downtime has not led to anything.

Here are some code snippets from my project:

Parent item:

```
  $( ".box" ).resizable({
stack: "#set .box",
start: function(){
    ifr = $('iframe');
    var d = $('<div></div>');

    $('.room').append(d[0]);
    d[0].id = 'temp_div';
    d.css({position:'absolute'});
    d.css({top: ifr.position(), left:0});
    d.height(ifr.height());
    d.width('100%');
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
      var w = ui.size.width;
      var h = ui.size.height;
      var hdvzth = ui.helper.data("hdvzth");
      var fid = ui.helper.data("fid");
      var rid = ui.helper.data("rid");
      var hid = ui.helper.data("hid");
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php print $position; ?>",
              data: { h: h, w: w,  fid:fid, hid:hid, rid:rid }
            }).done(function( msg ) {});
    $('#temp_div').remove();


      }
}


).draggable({

  stop: function(event, ui) {

      var pos_x = ui.position.left;
      var pos_y = ui.position.top;
      var hdvzth = ui.helper.data("hdvzth");
      var hid = ui.helper.data("hid");
      var fid = ui.helper.data("fid");
      var rid = ui.helper.data("rid");

      //Do the ajax call to the server
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php print $position; ?>",
          data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, fid:fid, rid:rid, hid:hid }
        }).done(function( msg ) { });
  }
});
```

Child Item, aka "icon":

```
$( ".piece" ).resizable({

stack: "#set .piece",
start: function(){
    ifr = $('iframe');
    var d = $('<div></div>');

    $('.piece').append(d[0]);
    d[0].id = 'temp_div';
    d.css({position:'absolute'});
    d.css({top: ifr.position(), left:0});
    d.height(ifr.height());
    d.width('100%');
},
stop: function(event, ui) {

      var x = ui.position.left;
      var y = ui.position.top;
      var w = ui.size.width;
      var h = ui.size.height;
      var hdvzth = ui.helper.data("hdvzth");
      var fid = ui.helper.data("fid");
      var pid = ui.helper.data("pid");
      var hid = ui.helper.data("hid");
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php print $position; ?>",
              data: { h: h, w: w, x: x, y: y, fid:fid, hid:hid, pid:pid }
            }).done(function(msg){});
            $('#temp_div').remove();
      }
}).draggable({

  stop: function(event, ui) {

      var pos_x = ui.position.left;
      var pos_y = ui.position.top;
      var pid = ui.helper.data("pid");
      var hid = ui.helper.data("hid");
      var fid = ui.helper.data("fid");

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php print $position; ?>",
          data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, fid:fid, pid:pid, hid:hid }
        }).done(function( msg ) {});
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. When you drag the larger div, do you want to drop it into a submit container or something? 2. About the ajax request: What do you exactly want to post to the server?

Comment: @Bluedayz, imagine this being like an apartment furniture arrangement app - just organizing icons within containers, and unlimited containers and icons that can have any position within the parent.

Code snippets added!